# Mongo DB - Lock collection and insert record

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to achieve centralization logic with multiple VM's. 
I have one application running on say 5 VM's. Only 1 VM will be responsible for doing one task. 
To have that I am writing that VM's host name to the database.But to update that name to database, I had to achieve locking using java client API, As there can be 2-3 VM coming up @ the same time. 
How to achieve that ?

UPDATE : 
I can use findandModify. But my code looks like this

```
{
  if(collection.getCount({"taskName" :"Task1"}) == 0){
    //insert record  ------ **I can use findAndModify here**
 }
}
```

But if two VM's come up at the same time then both will go inside if block, as the document is not available.
I understand that findAndModify is atomic. Hence After 1 VM issued findAndModify command we will have 1 record with hostname. But the next VM also will do the same operation and updates the record again with its hostname.

Please let me know if I am not clear with my question.

Comment: I have one word for you: `findAndModify`

Comment: Thanks. I had updated my question. Request you to check

Comment: use something like this: `findAndModify({hostname: ''}, {...})`. This way first VM will set its hostname, but the next one will fail to find a document (since now hostname is not empty)

Comment: Thank you Sergio Tulentsev, Your suggestion worked,

Answer (score 0):

Updates per document in mongodb are atomic. So you do not have to implement a locking mechanism on the client side. As the comment states check [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/findAndModify/#findandmodify) for your use case.

**Update**

On the query part you can check if document has "hostname" with [$exists](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/#op._S_exists). If document with Task1 has hostname, it means there is already a VM responsible for the task. I do not know your whole use case but lets say, that VM1 is finished with the task it can update document to remove the field "hostname". Or you can use for hostname a default value like '' and check if hostname with '' and taskName with 'Task1'.